# trouble binding parameters to an object and successfully save()

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy

I have a somewhat basic Q/A application and I'm having problem changing the order of my answers. The answers are displayed through the `Ordinal` property which has a `unique constraint`.

### answer domain

```
class Answer {

    DateTime dateCreated
    DateTime lastUpdated

    String body
    Integer ordinal
    String reason

    static belongsTo = [question: Question]

    static constraints = {
        body blank: false
        ordinal unique: 'question'
    }

    String toString() {
        "Answer: $body"
    }
}
```

### question domain

```
class Question {

    DateTime dateCreated
    DateTime lastUpdated

    String body
    Answer correctAnswer
    Integer ordinal

    static belongsTo = [lesson: Lesson]
    static hasMany = [answers: Answer]

    static constraints = {
        body blank: false
        correctAnswer nullable: true,
                validator: { Answer val, Question obj ->                    
                val ? val.question == obj : true // TODO: Give this a proper error message
            }
        ordinal unique: 'lesson'
    }

    static mapping = {
        lesson lazy: true
        answers sort: 'ordinal'
    }
}
```

I update the ordinals through a form

[image: form image]

```
<g:each status="i" in="${questionInstance.answers}" var="answer">
    <input type="number" name="answers[${i}].ordinal" value="${answer?.ordinal}" />: ${answer}
</g:each>
```

### update action

the params binds to the `questionInstance.answers` object and updates the `ordinal` fields the each answer

```
def update(Long id, Long version) {

    def questionInstance = Question.get(id)

    questionInstance.properties = params

    if (!questionInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "edit", model: [questionInstance: questionInstance])
        return
    }

    redirect(action: "index", id: questionInstance.id)
}
```

this is what my `questionInstance.answers` object looks like before I bind the `params`
[image: before]

after the `params` are assigned. Notice that `answers` has changed from `hibernate.collection.PersistentSet` to `grails.web.binding.ListOrderedSet`

[image: after]

### stacktrace

```
No signature of method: edu.example.work_department.website.Question$__clinit__closure1_closure3.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (edu.example.work_department.website.Answer, edu.example.work_department.website.Question) values: [Answer: Answer 2, edu.example.work_department.website.Question : 1]
Possible solutions: doCall(edu.example.work_department.website.Answer, edu.example.work_department.website.Question), call(), call([Ljava.lang.Object;), call(java.lang.Object), call(edu.example.work_department.website.Answer, edu.example.work_department.website.Question), findAll()
The following classes appear as argument class and as parameter class, but are defined by different class loader:
edu.example.work_department.website.Answer (defined by 'java.net.URLClassLoader@689319a1' and 'groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader@8db6e40'), edu.example.work_department.website.Question (defined by 'java.net.URLClassLoader@689319a1' and 'groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader@8db6e40')
If one of the method suggestions matches the method you wanted to call, 
then check your class loader setup.. Stacktrace follows:
'groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: edu.example.work_department.website.Question$__clinit__closure1_closure3.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (edu.example.work_department.website.Answer, edu.example.work_department.website.Question) values: [Answer: Answer 2, edu.example.work_department.website.Question : 1]
Possible solutions: doCall(edu.example.work_department.website.Answer, edu.example.work_department.website.Question), call(), call([Ljava.lang.Object;), call(java.lang.Object), call(edu.example.work_department.website.Answer, edu.example.work_department.website.Question), findAll()
The following classes appear as argument class and as parameter class, but are defined by different class loader:
edu.example.work_department.website.Answer (defined by 'java.net.URLClassLoader@689319a1' and 'groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader@8db6e40'), edu.example.work_department.website.Question (defined by 'java.net.URLClassLoader@689319a1' and 'groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader@8db6e40')
If one of the method suggestions matches the method you wanted to call,
```

The error occurs when hitting the `questionInstance.save()` command. What am I doing wrong that it doesn't like my argument types?

Comment: have you tried using bindData() instead of questionInstance.properties = params? e.g. bindData(questionInstance, params)

Comment: You should show the source for the `Question` class.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore same error as before. It still makes the questinoInstance a `listOrderSet` instead of a `persistent set`

Comment: @JeffScottBrown added question domain below the answer domain

Comment: Does the problem happen if you dynamically type the arguments to the custom validator?  `{ val, obj ->` instead of `{ Answer val, Question obj ->`?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown when I do that, I get this error message `A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: edu.wisc.radiology.spineprocedurewebsite.Question.answers`. I've seen that error message before, and in the past it meant I was creating a new instance of an object instead of updating it. Not sure why it's complaining this time

Comment: will reply soon when I have it figured out. I'm having trouble working on this particular case until I get another project done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to avoid data binding with

```
object.properties = params
```

Apart from this, you can use Command classes [grails command class creation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/validation.html#sharingConstraints)

And you can bind data using command class object.

For your Domain class `Answer`

create command class as :

```
Class AnswerCommand {      

    String body
    Integer ordinal
    String reason

    static constraints = {
        body blank: false
        ordinal unique: 'question'
    }
}
```

and read the params as command class object.

```
def update(Long id, Long version, AnswerCommand answerCmd) {

    def questionInstance = Question.get(id)

    //questionInstance.properties = params // use the below codes.

      questionInstance.body = answerCmd.body
      questionInstance.ordinal = answerCmd.ordinal
      questionInstance.reason = answerCmd.reason

    //here you can use bindData() also. But this is for making you a clear picture.


    if (!questionInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "edit", model: [questionInstance: questionInstance])
        return
    }

    redirect(action: "index", id: questionInstance.id)
}
```

Comment: Look forward to learning to use command objects. I've heard of them but never knew how to use them. Thanks